# SQL Server Stored Procedure for Menu Performance Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I have four tables in my SQL database i.e `MenuItems`, `Categories`, `Invoices` and `InvoiceDetails`. Now what I want is to show the menu performance report for a certain date i.e total Qty and total Amount for
each menu item for a specific date. It shows the desired result without the date in the where clause but excludes menu items with null values.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetMenuPerformanceByDay 
    @Date date, 
    @Terminal int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        M.Name, 
        ISNULL(SUM(D.Amount), 0) AS Amount,
        ISNULL(SUM(D.Qty), 0) AS Qty
    FROM
        MenuItems AS M 
    JOIN
        Categories AS C ON C.Id = M.CategoryId  
    LEFT JOIN 
        InvoiceDetails AS D ON M.Id = D.ItemId 
    LEFT JOIN 
        Invoices I ON I.Id = d.InvoiceId
    WHERE
        @Terminal IN (I.TerminalId, C.TerminalId) 
        AND CONVERT(date, I.Time) = @Date 
        OR NULL IN (Amount, Qty) 
    GROUP BY
        M.Name, M.Id, D.ItemId
    ORDER BY
        (Qty) DESC
END
```

The result this stored procedure returns on adding Date in where clause:

| Item | Amount | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KOFTA ANDA | 1950 | 3 |
| HOT N SOUR SOUP | 550 | 1 |
| CHICKEN CHOWMEIN | 250 | 1 |
| CHICKEN KORMA | 850 | 1 |

And the result I want is but don't get it on adding Date in where clause :

| Item | Amount | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KOFTA ANDA | 1950 | 3 |
| HOT N SOUR SOUP | 550 | 1 |
| CHICKEN CHOWMEIN | 250 | 1 |
| CHICKEN KORMA | 850 | 1 |
| CRISPY CHICKEN | 0 | 0 |
| MEXICAN BURGER | 0 | 0 |

[image: The design of the four Table is as below:]

Comment: `Null in (Amount,Qty)`  is never true. The only way to test column is null is `is null`

Comment: I dont want to test but add rows with null values. The problem is on adding date in where clause, excludes rows with null values.

Comment: If I Remove ` Convert(date,I.Time) = @Date ` From where clause then it gives the desired result but I want the result to be date oreinted.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Looks like you are missing brackets for the `OR`, also `NULL IN ...` never works because `NULL` is not equal to anything including itself. To top it off, `CONVERT(date` can cause performance issues. Try `AND ((I.Time >= CAST(CAST(@Date AS date) AS datetime) AND I.Time < CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(@Date AS date) AS datetime))) OR Amount IS NULL OR Qty IS NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

What if you don't put criteria for Invoices in the WHERE clause?

**Sample data**

> ```
> create table Categories (
>  Id int primary key, 
>  Name varchar(30) not null,
>  TerminalId int not null
> );
>
> create table MenuItems (
>  Id int identity(21,1) primary key, 
>  Name varchar(30) not null,
>  CategoryId int not null, 
>  foreign key (CategoryId) references Categories(Id)
> );
>
> create table Invoices (
>  Id int identity(31,1) primary key,
>  TerminalId int not null, 
>  ItemId int not null, 
>  Time datetime, 
>  foreign key (ItemId) references MenuItems(Id)
> );
>
> create table InvoiceDetails (
>  InvoiceDetailId int identity(41,1) primary key, 
>  InvoiceId int,
>  Amount decimal(10,2), 
>  Qty int, 
>  foreign key (InvoiceId) references Invoices(Id)
> );
>
> insert into Categories (Id, Name, TerminalId) values
> (1,'KOFTA', 1), 
> (2,'SOUP', 1), 
> (3,'CHICKEN', 1), 
> (4,'BURGER', 1);
>
> insert into MenuItems (CategoryId, Name) values
> (1,'KOFTA ANDA'), 
> (2,'HOT N SOUR SOUP'), 
> (3,'CHICKEN CHOWMEIN'), 
> (3,'CHICKEN KORMA'), 
> (3,'CRISPY CHICKEN'), 
> (4,'MEXICAN BURGER');
>
> insert into Invoices (ItemId, TerminalId, Time)
> select itm.Id, cat.TerminalId, GetDate() as Time
> from MenuItems itm
> join Categories cat on cat.Id = itm.CategoryId
> where itm.Name in (       
> 'KOFTA ANDA', 
> 'HOT N SOUR SOUP', 
> 'CHICKEN CHOWMEIN', 
> 'CHICKEN KORMA'
> );
>
> insert into InvoiceDetails (InvoiceId, Amount, Qty) values
> (31, 1950, 3),
> (32, 550, 1),
> (33, 250, 1),
> (34, 850, 1);
> ```

**Query**

> ```
> DECLARE @TerminalId INT = 1;
> DECLARE @Date DATE = GetDate();
>
> SELECT
>  V.[Date], 
>  C.Name AS Category, 
>  M.Name AS MenuItemName, 
>  ISNULL(SUM(D.Amount), 0) AS Amount,
>  ISNULL(SUM(D.Qty), 0) AS Qty
> FROM Categories AS C 
> CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Date AS [Date], @TerminalId AS TerminalId) V
> JOIN MenuItems AS M 
> ON M.CategoryId = C.Id
> LEFT JOIN Invoices I
>   ON I.ItemId = M.Id
>  AND I.TerminalId = V.TerminalId
>  AND CAST(I.Time AS DATE) = V.[Date]
> LEFT JOIN InvoiceDetails AS D 
>   ON D.InvoiceId = I.Id
> WHERE C.TerminalId = V.TerminalId
> GROUP BY V.[Date], C.Id, M.Id, C.Name, M.Name
> ORDER BY SUM(D.Qty) DESC
> ```

| Date | Category | MenuItemName | Amount | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-18 | KOFTA | KOFTA ANDA | 1950.00 | 3 |
| 2021-12-18 | SOUP | HOT N SOUR SOUP | 550.00 | 1 |
| 2021-12-18 | CHICKEN | CHICKEN CHOWMEIN | 250.00 | 1 |
| 2021-12-18 | CHICKEN | CHICKEN KORMA | 850.00 | 1 |
| 2021-12-18 | CHICKEN | CRISPY CHICKEN | 0.00 | 0 |
| 2021-12-18 | BURGER | MEXICAN BURGER | 0.00 | 0 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6e48da2df3019e9d5185008681fd77dd)*

Comment: The Problem is the date which is only contained in the invoices table. I need Menu Items report for a specific date

Comment: But you don't want to exclude the unmatched? So isn't it fine then?

Comment: But then it shows the overall report, not for a specific date. what if I need menu report performance for a month, week or a day

Comment: Maybe like this then.

Comment: Same Problem exists..

Comment: Could you include fake sample data? As text, or insert statement, or a fiddle?  It's a bit of an XY problem atm.

Comment: The problem is on adding date it excludes menu items from result that are not there in the InvoiceDetails table for that date. But I want them in result even if their amount and qty is null.

Comment: Let's say Total Number of Menu Items is 40 but only 30 of them were sold on 18/12/2021. Now what i want in the result is sum of amount and qty of those 30 items and remaining 10 items showing 0 as amount and Qty.

Comment: I want Both Sold and unsold items in the result set. At the moment, on adding date, it only provides items which were sold on that day and excludes items with Null as their amount and Qty

Comment: @DawoodJamil Check out the demo

Comment: Thanks to You bro.. @SMor Solution is what solved my problem.

Comment: @DawoodJamil If you need more dates or a range then you could join to a Calendar table. [Here's an example of how to create one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70218278/4003419).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my crack at your goal. Notice the changes. I found the reference to TerminalId in Category table highly suspicious - so much that I suspect it is a model flaw. Along those lines I note that TerminalId should likely have a foreign key to a missing table for Terminals. So I ignore that.

With that out, references to Category are now irrelevant. So that was removed as well. I also changed the procedure name since I find the reference to "day" misleading. It is highly likely "menu performance" would be evaluated on a "day" basis since retail (especially food service) sales vary by day of week consistently. So let's not mislead anyone thinking that is what this procedure does.

For simplicity and clarity, I removed the ISNULL usage. Add it back if desired but such things are usually better handled by the consumer of the resultset. I left the ORDER BY clause as a stub for you to re-evaluate (and you need to).

So how does this work? Simply calculate the sums directly in the CTE and then outer join from the menu items to the CTE sums to get **all menu items** along with the relevant performance information for the date specified.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetMenuPerformanceByDate
    @Date date, 
    @Terminal int
AS
BEGIN 
    with sales as (
       select det.ItemId, SUM(det.Amount) as amt, SUM(det.Qty) as qty 
         from dbo.Invoices as inv
        inner join dbo.InvoiceDetails as det 
           on inv.Id = det.InvoiceId
       where cast(inv.Time as date) = @Date 
         and inv.TerminalId = @Terminal 
       group by det.ItemId 
    )
    select menu.name, sales.amt, sales.qty 
      from dbo.MenuItems as menu
      left join sales 
        on menu.Id = sles.ItemId 
    order by ...
    ;
END;
```

One last note. This filter:

```
cast(inv.Time as date) = @Date
```

is generally not a good method of filtering a datetime column. Far better to use inclusive lower and exclusive upper boundaries like:

```
inv.Time >= @date and inv.Time < dateadd(day, 1, @date)
```

for [this reason](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea).

My last note - there is a potential flaw regarding MenuItems. Presumably "name" is unique. It is highly unlikely that multiple rows would have the same name, but "unlikely" is not a restriction. If you generate rows based on name and name turns out to NOT be unique, your results are difficult to interpret.

Comment: Thanks a ton mate. This was exactly what I was looking for.. Secondly just to add, terminal refers to a branch. Categories table has terminalId as FK in case different branches have different categories of food.

Comment: I added Category because I wanted report on the basis of date and terminal.

Comment: On adding Category Back into your solution, it works fine. Because categories are different at different terminals in my case and without adding category it mixes menu items of all terminals. Thanks a lot again. I appreciate your effort. It solved my problem.